armhf: openssl-libcrypto-fix: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
I'm trying to use miniconda on a project on rpi4b but I can't get it initialized. The problem seems to be the 32-bit operating system which starts to be out of use. It's a fresh install of bookworm.
I got miniconda from
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
and installed it normally, but any further action will crash into openssl-libcrypto-fix
conda list
# packages in environment at /home/nodered/miniconda3:
#
conda                     3.16.0                   py34_0  
conda-env                 2.4.2                    py34_0  
openssl                   1.0.1k                        1  
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py34_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py34_0  
python                    3.4.3                         1  
pyyaml                    3.11                     py34_1  
requests                  2.7.0                    py34_0  
sqlite                    3.8.4.1                       1  
xz                        5.0.5                         0  
yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         0  
nodered@maagitku:~ $ c^C
nodered@maagitku:~ $ conda create --name py35 python=3.5
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /home/nodered/miniconda3/envs/py35:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    openssl-1.0.2l             |                0         2.6 MB
    readline-6.2               |                2         552 KB
    sqlite-3.13.0              |                0         1.1 MB
    tk-8.5.18                  |                0         1.8 MB
    xz-5.2.3                   |                0         642 KB
    zlib-1.2.11                |                0         118 KB
    certifi-2016.2.28          |           py35_0         211 KB
    python-3.5.4               |                0        15.4 MB
    setuptools-36.4.0          |           py35_1         566 KB
    wheel-0.29.0               |           py35_0          82 KB
    pip-9.0.1                  |           py35_1         1.7 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        24.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:    2016.2.28-py35_0
    openssl:    1.0.2l-0        
    pip:        9.0.1-py35_1    
    python:     3.5.4-0         
    readline:   6.2-2           
    setuptools: 36.4.0-py35_1   
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0        
    tk:         8.5.18-0        
    wheel:      0.29.0-py35_0   
    xz:         5.2.3-0         
    zlib:       1.2.11-0        

Proceed ([y]/n)? yes

Fetching packages ...
openssl-1.0.2l 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03 789.99 kB/s
readline-6.2-2 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01 379.86 kB/s
sqlite-3.13.0- 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.25 MB/s
tk-8.5.18-0.ta 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01   1.19 MB/s
xz-5.2.3-0.tar 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.12 MB/s
zlib-1.2.11-0. 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 796.80 kB/s
certifi-2016.2 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 968.75 kB/s
python-3.5.4-0 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:32 491.59 kB/s
setuptools-36. 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01 441.02 kB/s
wheel-0.29.0-p 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 527.37 kB/s
pip-9.0.1-py35 100% |######################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03 452.36 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#########################################################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
/home/nodered/miniconda3/envs/py35/bin/.openssl-post-link.sh: line 7: /home/nodered/miniconda3/envs/py35/bin/.openssl-libcrypto-fix: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Error: Error: post-link failed for: openssl-1.0.2l-0
nodered@maagitku:~ $

Steps tried this far:

I tried installing only openssl and all openssl 1.0.2 versions with same error


I can move from miniconda to python venv so it's no biggy
